# Rails: I want to display a value in a browser but don't want to show application.htm.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the Sorcery Gem to do my login things. At one point I just want to hit a method and get back a 1 or 0 if the user email & password are present in the DB. I can do that with this code, but Rails also returns the application.html.erb file which I don't want. All i need is the 0 or 1 to appear. Nothing else. Wondering how I can disable the application.html.erb template for just this one method. I tried:

```
render :layout => false
```

but that also prevents my @status value from appearing in my one line view file.

```
def index
if @user = login(params[:email], params[:password])    
    @status = '1'
  else
    @status = '0'
  end 
end
```

And my index.html.erb file is just one line: 
    <%= @status %>

Thanks

Comment: `render layout: false` at the end of your `index` method should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your controller you can add

`layout false, :only => [:index]`

Instead of at the action level.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to render a text so you don't need a view and you don't have to worry about layouts and instance variables.  your code can be rewritten as

```
def index
  render text: login(params[:email], params[:password]) ? 1 : 0
end
```